# Trouble with this simple EditorTemplate for DateTime objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

I'd like to configure the EditorFor template for every datatime objects in any of my models.

I'm getting this error:

> \EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml(1): error CS1973:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named
>   'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

Here's the entire code that's inside of the EditorTemplate called, DateTime.cshtml places in the EditorTemplates folder.

Any ideas?

Here's what I call in my View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
</div>
```

And this is the custom EditorTemplate I made:

```
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "date-selector" });

THE EDITOR IS WORKING
```

Basically, for every datetime object in my models, I want to add the class "date-selector" to that html element. This is for jQueryUI purposes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems I just had to cast Model to (DateTime)Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an extension method as below:

```
 public static MvcHtmlString CalenderTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, "{0:M/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "datepicker text" });
    }
```

Then use in view as below:

```
@Html.CalenderTextBoxFor(model => model.Employee.HireDate)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the model type of the editortemplate. Add "@model DateTime" to the top of the cshtml file:

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "date-selector" }); 
THE EDITOR IS WORKING
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution of casting the dynamic object. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I had the same frustrating issue and I didn't want to create an EditorTemplate that applied to all DateTime values (there were times in my UI where I wanted to display the time and not a JQueryUI drop-down calendar).  In my research, the root issues I came across were:

- The standard **TextBoxFor** helper allowed me to apply a custom class of "date-picker" to render the unobtrusive JQueryUI calender, but TextBoxFor wouldn't format a DateTime without the time, therefore causing the calendar rendering to fail.
- The standard **EditorFor** would display the DateTime as a formatted string (when decorated with the proper attributes such as `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]`, but it wouldn't allow me to apply the custom "date-picker" class.

Therefore, I expanded upon @Ashraf's answer and created custom HtmlHelper class that has the following benifits:

- The method automatically converts the DateTime into the ShortDateString needed by the JQuery calendar (JQuery will fail if the time is present).
- By default, the helper will apply the required htmlAttributes to display a JQuery calendar, but they can be overridden if needs be.
- If the date is null, MVC will put a date of 1/1/0001 as a value.  This method replaces that with an empty string.

I post this here in hopes that it might help someone else at some point.  Any suggestions on changes needed are welcome.

```
public static MvcHtmlString CalenderTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  var mvcHtmlString = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, htmlAttributes ?? new { @class = "text-box single-line date-picker" });
  var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(mvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString());
  var xElement = xDoc.Element("input");
  if (xElement != null)
  {
    var valueAttribute = xElement.Attribute("value");
    if (valueAttribute != null)
    {
      valueAttribute.Value = DateTime.Parse(valueAttribute.Value).ToShortDateString();
      if (valueAttribute.Value == "1/1/0001")
        valueAttribute.Value = string.Empty;
    }
  }
  return new MvcHtmlString(xDoc.ToString());
}
```

And for those that want to know the JQuery syntax that looks for objects with the `date-picker` class decoration to then render the calendar, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.date-picker').datepicker({ inline: true, maxDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
  $('.date-picker').datepicker('option', 'showAnim', 'slideDown');
});
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future that has this need.